# Assigning groupings to records via a Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I apologize if I'm not explaining this very well. I have searched for an answer online, but most of the keywords I can think of have a technical meaning which dominates the search results!

OK, so I'm setting up an activities program. I have a bunch of attendees who can each select one activity per day of attendance. I have a bunch of leaders who can each staff one activity, with a maximum group size (say, 10).

What I need to do is to run a Stored Procedure overnight that will go through the list of attendees, select those who will be there the following day and then assign them to groups (by activity) with a maximum size and allocate a leader to the group.

For ease, I'm just going to have the group ID be the same as the Leader ID (since each Leader can only lead one group and each group needs a Leader.)

So the task is to go through everyone signed up for, say, Swimming and assign the first 10 to Leader A, the next 10 to Leader B and so on. Then move on to those who have signed up for, say, Hiking and assign the first 10 to Leader C, the next 10 to leader D....

I'm assuming I need some kind of ForEach loop to process the results of querying the attendees table for those attending the next day, but I'm kinda stuck on how to then process each activity separately and then put them into groups of 10.

I hope that makes some sense!

It seems to me that this kind of problem should be fairly standard. (Dividing passengers onto buses, products into shipping boxes, etc. It's all the same, basic, algorithm!)

TIA for all help and advice (of for just reading this.)

Edited to provide additional clarity:

So before the Stored Procedure, I may have my attendee table looking something like this:

```
ID|Activity|Day|Group
1 |    1   |Mon|
2 |    1   |Mon|
3 |    1   |Tue|
4 |    1   |Mon|
5 |    2   |Mon|
6 |    2   |Tue|
7 |    2   |Mon|
8 |    2   |Mon|
9 |    2   |Mon|
10|    2   |Mon|
```

I then might have a Leaders table like this:

```
ID|Activity
1 |   1    
2 |   1    
3 |   1    
4 |   2    
5 |   2    
6 |   2
```

To keep the example short, let's assume a group size of 2...

Following the SP call on Sunday night, I want the attendee table to look like this:

```
ID|Activity|Day|Group
1 |    1   |Mon|  1
2 |    1   |Mon|  1
3 |    1   |Tue|
4 |    1   |Mon|  2
5 |    2   |Mon|  4
6 |    2   |Tue|
7 |    2   |Mon|  4
8 |    2   |Mon|  5
9 |    2   |Mon|  5
10|    2   |Mon|  6
```

So, as you can see Attendees 3 & 6 were not allocated due to not attending on Monday. We then have two groups for Activity 1 (One of 2 and one of 1) and three groups for Activity 2 (Two of 2 and one of 1).

Note, Leader #3 isn't needed that day.

If I run out of leaders for an activity, then the attendees should not be allocated to a group.

Comment: *I'm assuming I need some kind of ForEach loop* In a relational database, never assume this. You need to provide sample data and expected results, please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the extremely rapid response!
I have edited my question to include an example of what I am trying to achieve. Please advise if additional clarification is required.

Comment: I should also mention that I have seen the NTILE() function, which looked promising, but that splits the records into a fixed number of groups each of which is as big as it needs to be. I, however, need to split into as many groups as are required for a fixed maximum size.

Comment: Perhaps you can start with something like `SELECT *, Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Activity, ORDER BY Id) FROM Leaders` and combine it with `SELECT *, Seq = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Activity, ORDER BY Id) - 1) / 2 + 1 FROM Attendees WHERE Day = 'Mon'`. One problem, is that the results may not be evenly distributed by the second query. If you can calculate the number of groups neeeded per activity ahead of time (A CTE perhaps) you can look at using NTIME for a more even distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that calculates classes needed per activity, uses NTILE to distribute the attendees into groups, and then matches them up with available leaders.

```
DECLARE @Capacity INT = 2;
DECLARE @Day VARCHAR(10) = 'Mon';

WITH CTE_Attendees AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM @Attendees
    WHERE Day = @Day
),
CTE_ClassesNeeded AS (
    SELECT Activity, ClassesNeeded = (COUNT(*) - 1) / @Capacity + 1
    FROM CTE_Attendees
    GROUP BY Activity
),
CTE_OrderedGroups AS (
    SELECT *, Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ACtivity ORDER BY ID)
    FROM @Leaders
    -- We could potentially limit the selected groups/leaders here,
    -- but excess will simply be ignored later.
),
CTE_Attendee_Assignments AS (
    SELECT OA.*, AssignedGroupID = OG.ID
    FROM CTE_ClassesNeeded CN
    CROSS APPLY (
        -- Need a cross apply to allow for a varying NTILE parameter
        SELECT *, Seq = NTILE(CN.ClassesNeeded) OVER(ORDER BY A.ID)
        FROM CTE_Attendees A
        WHERE A.Activity = CN.Activity
    ) OA
    LEFT JOIN CTE_OrderedGroups OG
        ON OG.Activity = CN.Activity
        AND OG.Seq = OA.Seq
)
SELECT SELECT ID, Activity, Day, AssignedGroupID
FROM CTE_Attendee_Assignments
ORDER BY ID;
-- TODO: Change the final select above into an update statement
```

Results

| ID | Activity | Day | AssignedGroupID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Mon | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | Mon | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | Mon | 2 |
| 5 | 2 | Mon | 4 |
| 7 | 2 | Mon | 4 |
| 8 | 2 | Mon | 5 |
| 9 | 2 | Mon | 5 |
| 10 | 2 | Mon | 6 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e537ab215791d29ad7bd8273eb274f3e) for a working example.

Notes: For the capacity = 4 case, the five activity 2 attendees are split into two classes of 3 and 2. For the capacity = 1 case, some attendees receive no assignments due to full classes.

Comment: Thank you! I will work through this and inwardly digest :-)